# Google API p12 key not readable: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

FOR ANYONE FINDING THIs - this error was due to the .p12 being corrupt after downloading on a win7 box. After downloading to a unix machine the cert worked.

I have followed about a million different guides trying to get this to work.

I am trying to connect to the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) with a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

I have the relevant "project" created in the console, given said project access to the relavent API's required.

In the credentials I have added the service account in the OAuth section, downloaded the p12 key and stored on server.

When I run the code:

```
//start the google v3 api server authorization with the .p12 key
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("AnalyticsAPI");

    $key = __DIR__ . '/google-keys/AnalyticsAPI-XXXXXX.p12';

    $credentials = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        '101XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXnq4omne@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
        $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
    //auto refresh if old
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($credentials);
    }

    //start the analytics shtuff
    $service = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);  
    $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

    //Adding Dimensions
    $params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath');
    // requesting the data
    $data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:$profile_id", $start_date,  $end_date, "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );

    print_r($data);
```

The error is thrown from the "Google/Signer/P12.php on line 52"

```
Unable to parse the p12 file. Is this a .p12 file? Is the password correct? OpenSSL error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag in /XXXXX/classes/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Signer/P12.php on line 52
```

The error is thrown from ...Signer/P12.php @ 49:

```
// This throws on error
      $certs = array();
      if (!openssl_pkcs12_read($p12, $certs, $password)) {
        throw new Google_Auth_Exception(
            "Unable to parse the p12 file.  " .
            "Is this a .p12 file?  Is the password correct?  OpenSSL error: " .
            openssl_error_string()
        );
      }
```

When i extract the relavent code attempting to read the .p12 file and run on its own i get the same error:

```
$certs = array();
    openssl_pkcs12_read($key, $certs, 'notasecret');
    print_r($certs);
    echo openssl_error_string();
    die(x);


Array ( ) error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
```

I'm completely stumped. Reading some other posts on the issue like this one:
[Getting "Unable to parse the p12 file..." Error With google-api-php-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079057/getting-unable-to-parse-the-p12-file-error-with-google-api-php-client)

I have tried

1. Ensuring permissions are correct.
2. `file_get_contents($key)` and then passing to the `openssl_pkcs12_read` which yields the same results!

Does anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the latest clint lib from [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
2. give The service account email address access to read Google Analytics at the **ACCOUNT** level
3. Try this tutorial [Google Service Account with PHP](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/)

   ```
   session_start();        
   require_once 'Google/Client.php';

   require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';    

   /************************************************   
   The following 3 values an befound in the setting    
   for the application you created on Google       
   Developers console.      Developers console.
   The Key file should be placed in a location  
   that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
   web root.        web root.

   In order to access your GA account you must 
   Add the Email address as a user at the  
   ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.      
   ************************************************/

   $client_id = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp.apps.googleusercontent.com';
   $Email_address = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp@developer.gserviceaccount.com';     
   $key_file_location = '629751513db09cd21a941399389f33e5abd633c9-privatekey.p12';     
   $client = new Google_Client();      
   $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

   $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);   

   // seproate additional scopes with a comma   
   $scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

   $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(

       $Email_address,      
   array($scopes),     
   $key         
   );      
   $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
   if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
           $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);       
   }       
   $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
   $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

   //calulating start date  
   $date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));     
   $date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));    
   //Adding Dimensions
   $params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType'); 
   // requesting the data  
   $data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:78110423", $date->format('Y-m-d'), date("Y-m-d"), "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );  
   ?><html>     
   <?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . " - ".date("Y-m-d"). "\n";?>    
   <table>  
   <tr>     
   <?php    
   //Printing column headers
   foreach($data->getColumnHeaders() as $header){
           print "<td>".$header['name']."</td>";       
   }       
   ?>      
   </tr>       
   <?php       
   //printing each row.
   foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {        
           print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";   
   }    
   //printing the total number of rows
   ?>      
   <tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $data->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>     
   </table>     
   </html>
   ```

code ripped from the previously mentioned tutorial.

Comment: Hi DalmTo, thanks but it turns out the error was fixed by downloading the .p12 from a unix machine instead of a windows. God knows why.. I am getting the std google error message in return now instead of the cannot read cert. Will ensure all the analytics settings are now correct :-)

Comment: weird I do everything on a windows machine.  I have never had problems with uploading the .p12 keys to the server after.

Comment: I was rsyncing the cert via cwrsync from windows to unix.. was thinking it could be to do with that, but then i got a colleague to email me the cert downloaded from a mac, rsynced that to the server and it worked... i have no idea. Very confusing :O

Comment: I am going to have to try and recreate this still seams weird.

Comment: The updating to the newest version of the client library did it for me. Thank you :)