# 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Unable to parse the p12 file?

Tags: google-calendar-api

[image]

I get this error.
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079057/getting-unable-to-parse-the-p12-file-error-with-google-api-php-client

Comment: Please tel what is the key_file_location in google calander